# Pass through parameter

Tags: luigi

Based on the documentation: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameters.html

"You can run TaskB on the command line: luigi TaskB --y 42. But you can also set the class value of TaskA by running luigi TaskB --y 42 --TaskA-x 43. "

How can I do that from Luigi.build rather than command line? My problem is that I have task a, requiring task b, requiring task c; and task c needs to have set a parameter, but I don't want to create that parameter in all previous tasks just to carry it forward, so I though that I could use it from Luigi.build, but don't know exactly how

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is to add this to `luigi.cfg`

```
[TaskC]
z= 123
```